# useSelector not updating with Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I've been battling this all day long and I'd appreciate any help.

I have a redux store built with Redux Toolkit and createSlice that looks like so:

```
const initialState = {
  analiticaNumber: "",
  animal: {},
  tests: [{ key: "G9116", value: "DERMATOFITOS PCR/ MUESTRA" }],
};

const PeticionSlice = createSlice({
  name: "peticion",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addTest: (state, action) => {
      state.tests.push(action.payload);
    },
  },
});

export const { addTest: addTestActionCreator } = PeticionSlice.actions;

export const testsArray = (state) => state.Peticion.tests;

export default PeticionSlice.reducer;
```

I also have a root reducer that imports the rest of the slices and names them as such

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import NavigationSlice from "./NavigationSlice";

const RootReducer = combineReducers({
  Peticion: PeticionSlice,
});

export default RootReducer;
```

When I add tests to the tests array it works fine and shows in the redux devtools.

The promblem comes that react does not see the change in the store and won't update the child component:

`import { testsArray } from "./Store/PeticionSlice";`
That's how I import namely the testsArray to call with the useSelector.
The tradicional way of `const { tests } = useSelector( (state) => state.Peticion)` doesn't work either.

```
function App() {
  const tests = useSelector(testsArray);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("tests");
  }, [tests]);

  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <div className="App">
        <nav>
          <Navbar />
        </nav>
        {tests.map((test) => (
          <p>{test.key}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}
```

I belive it has to do something with the mutability of the state, but I thought the toolkit took care of that, and for the life of me I don't know how to solve this.

Any help??? Thanks a lot.

** UPDATE **

I believe it has to do with the way I dispatch the actions. Because I needed to add several boundaries to what the app does, I decided to have an external function that filters and dispatches accordingly. It is not a react component.

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { addTestToList, addTestActionCreator } from "../Store/PeticionSlice";
import RootReducer from "../Store/RootReuder";

const PruebasToSubmitArray = [];

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: RootReducer,
});

const handleTestList = (test, action) => {
  const anatomia = "A";
  const microbiologia = "M";

  function oneBiopsia() {
    while (test.key.toString().charAt(0) === anatomia) {
      return PruebasToSubmitArray.some(
        (pruebaInArray) => pruebaInArray.key.toString().charAt(0) === anatomia
      );
    }
    return false;
  }

  if (!oneBiopsia() && action === "add") {
    switch (test.key.toString().charAt(0)) {
      case anatomia:
        // console.log("Open pdf for anatomia");
        store.dispatch(addTestActionCreator(test));
        break;
      case microbiologia:
        // console.log("Open pdf for micro");
        store.dispatch(addTestActionCreator(test));
        break;
      default:
        // console.log("add test to the list, ", test);
        store.dispatch(addTestActionCreator(test));
        break;
    }
  } else if (action === "remove") {
    // console.log("remove test from the list, ", test);
  } else if (oneBiopsia()) {
    console.log("Only one biopsia per peticion, ", newState);
  }

  return null;
};

export default handleTestList;
```

I added a button on App component and it worked as expected (i showed the updated state), as is right now redux updates the state but the component won't reflect it.

[Code SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-waterfall-thbxz?file=/src/index.js) as complete as I can

Comment: Can you provide your code on codesandbox or similar platform ? It would help to debug it.

Comment: where does `testsArray` in your code come from?

Comment: I've created a sandbox based on your code and it works just fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-mccarthy-9bkph?file=/src/App.js . How does `testsArray` look like? Please add the code to your question.

Comment: Well, I just created the sand box and of course it works there https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-waterfall-thbxz?file=/src/App.js:497-517

Comment: My dispatch looks different though, i have it in a different file in a switch statement, but that should be the problem given that the redux can see the change

Comment: You have two people asking you for `testsArray` now, because there is a 99% likelyness that that (or generally your usage of useSelector) is your bug. Why do you look in other places and not answer that question?

Comment: I just added the ```testArray``` It is just another way of calling the state with the useSelector, the conventional ```const { tests } = useSelector((state) => state.Peticion.tests``` didn't work either

Comment: I have a RootReducer that does that. Sorry for the confusion, I just added the part of the code. I know it connects the first time because I can log the initial state of the store and also shows the exisitng object in the array. Thanks for helping BTW

Comment: @CodeAlga Does it also show the added tests when you dispatch the action? Did you confirm in the redux devtools, that your store contains the added test? Are there any error messages in the console? Is the way you render the tests exactly the same as presented in the code of the question?

Comment: @trixn by parts: 1 I can see in the redux devtooks the tests beeing added, 2: no errors on the console 3: As of right now it is, later it will go on a child component (it will go on a table but I'm taking things from the middle). Shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Where is `handleTestList` called? It's not as helpful to add more code (which is still incomplete and not runnable) without confirming it is needed to reproduce the problem. Please create a sandbox that has the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem so we can debug it. If you can't find the issue while being able to run the code, how is anybody supposed to find a problem by just looking at huge amounts of incomplete code snippets?

Comment: I'm sorry for making it complicated. I do appreciate the help and the time. The application is a bit big and it's beeing updated by chunks. I makes it a bit complicated to isolate some things. I added the link to the sandBox at the end of the post. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Multiple Instances of Store

You create a `store` variable in your `index.js` file and pass that store to the react-redux `Provider` component.  This is the store instance which all react-redux `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks will interact with.

In your `HandleTestList.js` file you create a different `store` variable.  You then `dispatch` actions to that store, but those actions won't be reflected in your React app because this isn't the store that your React app uses.

`handleTestList` needs to either A) import the same global `store` variable.  You will want to move this out of `index.js` and into `store.js` to avoid circular dependencies. or B) accept `dispatch` as an argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight @Linda. I knew that I had to give access to the store in order to dispatch, but not that I was creating another store by doing so. I opted for the second solution, and passed the dispatch as an argument. Thanks!! :D

Answer (score 3):

Very odd behavior in my case.

I did

```js
state = action.payload
```

and that didn't work.

Once I switched to

```js
state.viewer = action.payload.viewer
```

everything worked!

Comment: This happens because react toolkit uses Immer for state changes. Immer updates the state immutably when you return an object or when you mutate the state. Assigning something else into `state` is neither of those.