# UseSelector returns undefined even the state is updated correctly

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I have a react admin project using React Redux.

Below is the detail:

```
slice.tsx:

import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const newRevisionSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'newRevision',
    initialState: {
      dataList: [],
      status: 'idle'
    },
  reducers: {
    postSaveNewRevision: (state  = { dataList:[], status:"idle" }, action) => {
      return { ...state, dataList: action.payload, status: 'success' };

      }
    }
  });


export const { postSaveNewRevision } = newRevisionSlice.actions;
export default newRevisionSlice.reducer;
```

```
component.tsx: 

const newRevision  = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.newRevision)
```

```
store.tsx:

declare global {
  interface Window {
    __REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__?: typeof compose;
  }
}

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  fleetType: fleetTypeApi,
  revisionNo: revisionNoApi,
  revisionDate:revisionDateApi,
  newRevision: newRevisionApi,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

const useAppDispatch = () => store.dispatch;

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

export { useAppDispatch };

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In react redux devtool I see that the state is updated correctly when I dispatch.
However, useSelector so newRevision in the component returns undefined.

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi all, I see in the console.log that the state is equal to an object but does not contain my reducers. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Is there by any chance your `newRevisionSlice` and the `newRevisionApi` in `store.jsx` are 2 different reducers? If that is the case, then you have 2 separate stores for `newRevision` and they won't share states.

Similar issues that are resolved:

- [useSelector not updating with Redux Toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66707823/useselector-not-updating-with-redux-toolkit)
- [useSelector state returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65481217/useselector-state-returns-undefined-react-redux)

Additionally, because your `useSelector()` return `undefined` it could also be the case that there is a typo somewhere with the names of slices / reducers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've checked and there are not 2 different reducers and also there is not typo. What can be the other problems? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Begumm, I noticed another pattern with using `redux-toolkit` that it seems to be best practice to mutate `state` directly inside reducer instead of returning a new object `{ ...state, dataList: action.payload, status: 'success' }` like in your case. Can you try ```(state) => { state.dataList = action.payload; state. status = 'success'; } ``` instead and let me know if it solves? [Source here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68381191/redux-useselector-returns-state-as-undefined)

Comment: Hi @kvooak, thanks but again undefined :(

Comment: @Begumm even if that doesn't solve your issue, my bet is still on the side of what it does inside your `createSlice()` reducer and the way data is returned, because your `useSelector()` returned `undefined` where it should have returned even the `initialState` with empty dataList and "idle" status instead. Either the way reducer returns new state or the access path to that state is incorrect.

Comment: @Begumm I would like to try the code on my local and debug it if you can somehow share it

Comment: It would be great @kvooak. I will inform you. Thanks

Comment: you can fetch the code from https://github.com/begumaydin29/testredux.git. Waiting a response from you. Thanks much :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243361/discussion-between-kvooak-and-begumm).